# consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: swift

I'm setting lldb command alias for reveal.

commands are following:

```
command alias reveal_load_sim expr (void*)dlopen("/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/libReveal.dylib", 0x2);
command alias reveal_load_dev expr (void*)dlopen([(NSString*)[(NSBundle*)[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"libReveal" ofType:@"dylib"] cStringUsingEncoding:0x4], 0x2);
command alias reveal_start expr (void)[(NSNotificationCenter*)[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IBARevealRequestStart" object:nil];
command alias reveal_stop expr (void)[(NSNotificationCenter*)[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IBARevealRequestStop" object:nil];
```

But when I set a break point and add debugger command `reveal_load_sim` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I got this error:

> error: :1:8: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
>
> ```
> (void*)dlopen("/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/libReveal.dylib", 0x2)
>        ^
>        ;
> ```

I googled a lot and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Is the last ";" really on a line by itself?

Comment: You should add a language tag to the question and platform. Presumably it is Objective-C and iOS.

Comment: @zaph Added. Swift and ios

Comment: @zaph Yes, itself on one line

Comment: If you are going to use Swift you are going to have to learn the syntax. Swift is not a small language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` in the error message is saying that `(void*)` is considered one statement and the rest of the line a second statement. So, as is common the error message is 1/2 right. Just delete `(void*)`, that is just part of the C declaration.

Swift:
    dlopen("/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/libReveal.dylib", 0x2)

Since no language was specified in the original question Objective-C was assumed, that turns out to have been wrong.

Objective-C:
You have a combination of a declaration and a function call. What you need is either:

```
dlopen("/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/libReveal.dylib", 0x2);
```

or

```
void *handle = dlopen("/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/libReveal.dylib", 0x2);
```

depending if you need the returned handle, probably not.

Comment: Yes, it's the case. But I can call the command in lldb command line in Xcode. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a strange Frankenstein's monster of mixed syntax. It looks to be mostly Objective-C and a little Swift syntax mixed in to confuse things. It's not legal anything. Not by a long shot.

None of your square brackets belong in the 3rd, 4th and 5th lines.

None of your `(classname*)` typecasts are correct in Swift. (Swift uses the syntax `type(objectToCast)` for typecasting.)

Comment: Yes, I just copied them from a blog teaching Reveal. Maybe he is using Objective-C

Comment: @Duncan C I believe the top four lines are lldb commands, that is not clear from the question though. BTW, is codementor.com alive?